# Syntax error in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and I am using python 3. I have an if statement which is recieving an error, but I do not know why. It's the line that says print new_word after the second if statement that is receiving the error. I indented it.

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
word = original.lower()
first = word[0]
new_word = word[1:] + first + pyg

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    if first == "o" or first == "i" or first == "e" or first == "u":
        print new_word
    else: print new_word
else:
    print word
```

Comment: Well, that one doesn't have the raw_input syntax issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.x, `print` is a function, so you must call it as:

```
print("Some string here")
```

Also, in [Python 3.x you should use `input(...)`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input) instead of `raw_input(...)`

Comment: Ahh, I must be learning from python 2 tutorials. I am using CodeAcademy.

I need to learn the differences then.